# Paho updating userdata from on_message callback

Tags: python, callback, global-variables, paho, user-data

Basically, I want my userdata to act as a global flag that gets read and updated between successive executions of the `on_message()` callback. I wrote and ran the following script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
MQTT_SERVER = "broker.hivemq.com"
MQTT_TOPIC = "IvanHu"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC)
    
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(userdata, end = '')
    print(" message received.")
    userdata += 1
    user_data_set(client_userdata)

client_userdata = 1

client = mqtt.Client(userdata=client_userdata)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

I then published to the topic IvanHu 4 times. I expect the output of my python paho script to be the following:

```
Connected with result code 0
1 message received.
2 message received.
3 message received.
4 message received.
```

However, this was what I got instead:

```
Connected with result code 0
1 message received.
1 message received.
1 message received.
1 message received.
```

Evidently, the variable client_userdata never got updated in successive on_message() calls. What is the correct way to update this variable?

Comment: It looks like `userdata` is incremented in the `on_message` function but never used again: you pass the `client_userdata` variable (which is always equal to `1`) to the `user_data_set` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out a way to satisfy my requirement using the userdata approach, but I was able to do so with the global variables approach. Here's the working script:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
MQTT_SERVER = "broker.hivemq.com"
MQTT_TOPIC = "IvanHu"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC)
    
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    global client_userdata
    print(client_userdata, end = '')
    print(" message received.")
    client_userdata += 1

client_userdata = 1

client = mqtt.Client()
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Output:

```
Connected with result code 0
1 message received.
2 message received.
3 message received.
4 message received.
```

The "global variables" approach doesn't use the userdata sent to MQTT broker, but instead increments "locally" the value of the variable. It counts locally the number of times was received the "on_message" callback.
Adding a print to display the "userdata" variable as received from MQTT broker will show that its value is always none since never defined in the MQTT client definition or set after its creation.

Answer (score 3):

You have to give a initial value for userdata by `client.user_data_set` before connection, then you can update the userdata in `on_message` callback.

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt
MQTT_SERVER = "broker.hivemq.com"
MQTT_TOPIC = "IvanHu"

# The callback for when the client receives a CONNACK response from the server.
def on_connect(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("Connected with result code "+str(rc))
    client.subscribe(MQTT_TOPIC)
    
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(userdata, end = '')
    print(" message received.")
    user_data_set(userdata + 1)    # <-- Update userdata

client_userdata = 1

client = mqtt.Client(userdata=client_userdata)
client.on_connect = on_connect
client.on_message = on_message
client.user_data_set(1)    # <-- Initialize
client.connect(MQTT_SERVER, 1883, 60)

client.loop_forever()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have missed the bit in the docs that talks about updating the `user_data` object

> It may be updated at a later point with the user_data_set() function.

Taken from the docs [here](https://www.eclipse.org/paho/index.php?page=clients/python/docs/index.php#constructor-reinitialise)

This means you need to pass the new value to `set_userdata()` so it should be as follows:

```
# The callback for when a PUBLISH message is received from the server.
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
    print(userdata, end = '')
    print(" message received.")
    userdata += 1
    client.user_data_set(userdata)
```

Comment: unfortunately, changing `user_data_set(client_userdata)` to `user_data_set(userdata)` didn't change the outcome. Still `1 message received.` four times. I actually tried your suggestion last night and re-confirmed this morning.

Comment: Sorry, typo. It should be `client.user_data_set(user_dara)`

Answer (score 0):

You actually should rather use some reference type like dict or so.

```
# Once you create the client, set some dict as user data
client.user_data_set({"counter": 0})

# When you get on_message, you can then edit just the key value, so the reference will take care of the data handling
def on_message(client, userdata, msg):
   userdata["counter"] += 1
```

In your example the user data is number, so once you increment it the reference gets overridden so the userdata is then used only locally.

Also, it would be safer to use mutex or so to change the data.